# Возможность иногда представлена, а иногда предоставлена?

Tags: пунктуация, паронимы

Обсуждение ответов Справки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Культура письменной речи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня возможность - что сделана?

> И, кстати, самое интересное, когда предоставляется
> возможность обнаружить для зрителя так называемый «второй план», то,
> что герой скрывает от окружающих.

А запятая после союза перед вводным?

«Второму плану» не мешает (здесь) *так называемый*?

---

Ещё авторитет глаголет - профессорша:

**[Представляется или предоставляется? Как правильно?](http://animelux.ru/11931/)**

> На нашем портале я уже писала о паре глаголов
> *представить/предоставить*.
>
> В современной речи выбор одного из них многих ставит в тупик. Смешение
> этих паронимов (близкозвучных, но разных по смыслу слов) привело к
> тому, что в речи появился глагол *предоставится*, которого на самом деле
> нет в языке!
>
> Значит, предложение должно строиться так: *В будущем нам представится
> возможность посетить все достопримечательности Москвы.* Глагол
> *представиться* имеет в этом случае такое значение: возникнет, появится
> (значение зафиксировано толковыми словарями).
>
> Если же мы хотим сказать о том, что кто-то или что-то нам подарят
> возможность, тогда выбираем глагол *предоставить* (в одной из его форм).
>
> Например: *Эта возможность предоставлена мне департаментом образования.
> Спасибо за предоставленную возможность.*

Запутали вконец! Помогите сироте...

---

Дополнение (про смущающую запятую). Нашла сама!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-моему, нужно убрать кавычки: так называемый второй план. Термин "второй план" сам по себе не требует кавычек, наличие кавычек имеет тот же смысл, что слова "так называемый".

Comment: Я бы поставил тире вместо запятой: "пред(о)ставляется возможность обнаружить так называемый второй план - то, что герой скрывает от окружающих". Тире отделяет уточненение.

Comment: Спасибо! Предложу автору.

Comment: "Второй план" образа не тянет на термин, скорее - профессиональный арготизм. Покажу и спрошу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Права профессорша: один из глаголов почти всегда "возвратно-поступательный": возможность склонна **представляться** *сама* либо быть **предоставленной** (**предоставляться**) *другими* человеческими существами или составленными из них организациями. С существенно иным смыслом (напр. в порядке *презентации* новой технической возможности расщепления чего-нибудь) можно употребить и выражение "*представить возможность*" ( с глаголом без возвратной частицы). Глагол *предоставиться* (кем-то), конечно, может быть формально образован, но вряд ли с ним получится складное предложение.

В вашем случае нужно знать, режиссером ли зрителю сознательно **предоставляется** возможность просветления вторым планом, или зрителю, угодившему на спектакль, **представляется** редкая возможность что-то уяснить. Но в обоих случаях не "для зрителя", а "зрителю".

**P.S.**
Про само предложение. Если "возможность" исходит от актёра, то она пред**о**ставляется или (более ясный вариант) её пред**о**ставляют; "и кстати" в начале предложения воспринимается как единая конструкция (а кстати, ну вот, а поворотись-ка, сынку и т п.) - вряд ли запятая полезна; кавычки при явном указании "так называемый" тоже не нужны:

> И кстати, самое интересное - это когда зрителю предоставляется (=
>   предоставляют) возможность обнаружить так называемый второй план, то,
>   что герой скрывает от окружающих.

Comment: Конечно, "зрителю" лучше, чем "для зрителя", но можно ли считать "для зрителя" недопустимым в таком варианте: "представляется (=случается) возможность для зрителя обнаружить (что-либо)"? Сравните: существует возможность для зрителя обнаружить (что-либо).

Comment: Думаю, что с точки зрения сочетаемости с падежами и предлогами к "представилась" и "была предоставлена" по смыслу ближе другие глаголы: "явилась" (подобно серафиму - без предлога; если возможность "представилась" кому-то, то она была осознана и в силу своей привлекательности использована, либо была сознательно проигнорирована) и "была адресована" (кем-то кому-то - не сочетается с для...) соответственно.

Comment: Саша, спасибо; отправлю автору для дальнейших раздумий. / Актёром даётся возможность зрителю прочувствовать "второй план" героя. / Добавьте, пожалуйста, для полноты картины (ответа) что-нибудь про запятую в *и, кстати*.